# Arc issues in iphone

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am developing an iphone by taking `singleviewapplication` template but select ARC check box.In my Application need of third Framework but when I run my Application so many errors occered.
All errors are related to ARC. How can I fix these error? Can any one help to me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile some files without ARC by using the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag on these files.

Quote from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project).

> You add compiler flags in Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. You have to double click on the right column of the row under Compiler Flags. You can also add it to multiple files by holding the cmd button to select the files and then pressing enter to bring up the flag edit box.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer these tutorials. They are easy to understand.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5773/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the framework you are using doesn't use ARC. To fix this, uncheck Use ARC in your project settings.

To leave the framework as it is and use ARC for the rest of your project, in xcode, go to Edit>Refactor>Convert to Objective-C ARC and in the dialoge box that appears, select all the files that you want to use ARC (i.e Application delegate, View Controllers, UIViews...)